# Disable web browser's options controls in winforms

Tags: winforms, webbrowser-control

I have used web browser control in my windforms application for integration nicEditor. I am using it for displaying and editing. How can I disable the options of that web browser. Like when we right click we get options to go back and reload the page etc. How can i disable that in winforms.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by setting web browser control's IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled property to false.

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)